# How to Show Data in CKEditor from Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, laravel, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in laravel 8. But can not show data in ckeditor From Ajax.
Here is my Ajax Code.

```
 $('.edit').on('click', function() {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'support-ticket-by-id',
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        $('#ajaxModelTitle').html("Edit");
                        $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
                        $('#id').val(res.id);
                        $('#edit_support_ticket_department_id').val(res
                            .support_ticket_department_id);
                        $('#edit_support_ticket_employee_id').val(res
                            .support_ticket_employee_id);
                        $('#support_ticket_priority').val(res.support_ticket_priority);
                        $('#support_ticket_subject').val(res.support_ticket_subject);
                        $('#support_ticket_note').val(res.support_ticket_note);
                        $('#support_ticket_date').val(res.support_ticket_date);
                        // $('#edit_support_ticket_desc').val(res.support_ticket_desc);
                        $('#support_ticket_status').val(res.support_ticket_status);
                    }
                });
            });
```

[image: [Ajax Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtNwr.jpg)]
Ajax Response

I want to show

```
support_ticket_desc
```

value in CkEditor.
Note: I used CkEditor in textarea html tag.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CKEDITOR.instances['edit_support_ticket_desc'].setData(res.support_ticket_desc)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- This is working for me -->

$(document).on('click','.editbtn',function(){
        $('#cate_image').empty();
            var cate_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               url:"{{url('admin/category/edit')}}"+'/'+cate_id,
               dataType:'json',
               success:function(res){
                 $('#name').val(res.name);
                 $('#slug').val(res.slug);
                 $('#cate_image').append('<img src="{{URL::asset('')}}'+'/'+res.image+'" height="150px" width="200px">');
                 $('#ci_alt').val(res.image_alt_name);
                 $('#sort_order').val(res.sort_order);
                 $('#meta_title').val(res.meta_title);
                 $('#meta_description').val(res.meta_description);
                 CKEDITOR.instances['description'].setData(res.description); 
           CKEDITOR.instances['custom_script_code'].setData(res.custom_script_code); 
    CKEDITOR.instances['facebook_pixel_code'].setData(res.facebook_pixel_code);
    CKEDITOR.instances['google_analytics'].setData(res.google_analytics);                 
               }
            });
         });
```